# Conditions on gem requirement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

I would like to prevent the updating of a gem on my windows (`rmagick`), so it sticks to `2.12.0 mswin32`. Still, my coworker needs to have the gem on his Darwin install...

So, I tried to do something like this in the `Gemfile`:

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/i
  gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.12.0'
else
  gem 'rmagick', '=2.12.0.mswin32'
end
```

but `bundle install` complaints.

What is the right way of handling this properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use conditionals on gemspec because gemspec is serialized
into YAML, which doesn't contain executable code.

I faced a related problem in the `Gemfile` of a local Rails project (not a
gem).

Currently, the Gemfile contains:

```
group :test do
...
# on Mac os X
  gem 'rb-fsevent' if RUBY_PLATFORM.include?("x86_64-darwin")
  gem 'ruby_gntp' if RUBY_PLATFORM.include?("x86_64-darwin")

# on Linux
  gem 'rb-inotify' unless RUBY_PLATFORM.include?("x86_64-darwin")
  gem 'libnotify' unless RUBY_PLATFORM.include?("x86_64-darwin")
end
```

This works (although it is ugly) for developing on Mac and Linux 
systems.

But, we stopped checking in the `Gemfile.lock` since it changes every time
a developer with a different platform checks in the code.

So, a solution for multi-platform Gemfiles should also solve the
problem for `Gemfile.lock`.

The other solutions is building multiple **.gemspec files** for each target OS and change both platform and dependencies for each platform:

```
gemspec = Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.platform = Gem::Platform::RUBY
end

# here build the normal gem

# Now for linux:
gemspec.platform = "linux"
gemspec.add_dependency ...

# build the newer gemspec
...
```

Comment: I tried the first option but it does not work when the gem you are trying to specify in each case is the same one with different version requirement. `bundle install` says something like: You cannot specify a gem twice. Or at least I don't know how to syntax that correctly (inputs welcome). I'll try your version two and I'll get back to you, thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: Part of the problem I have is specifying the version number. `gem list` says I have `rmagick 2.12.0 mswin32`. Now, you can't put spaces into your gem version specification inside `Gemfile`, so I tried `"=2.12.0.mswin32"` but `bundle install` doesn't match this to what the gem list says as it understands that as two different things. Any input here is VERY appreciated.

Comment: I really don't know but I did the similar way and it worked. I think this may help you- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ruby-bundler/lhgUTiAfL50 AND http://forum.redminebacklogs.net/can-t-cleanly-install-RBL-quot-same-gem-twice-with-different-version-requirements-quot-td4025469.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [platforms](https://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html#PLATFORMS) option Bundler provides:

> If a gem should only be used in a particular platform or set of
> platforms, you can specify them. Platforms are essentially identical
> to groups, except that you do not need to use the --without
> install-time flag to exclude groups of gems for other platforms.

So in your specific case that would look something like this:

```
gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.12.0', :platforms => :ruby
gem 'rmagick', '=2.12.0.mswin32', :platforms => :mswin
```

Comment: I tried your solution: it leads to `bundle install
    You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version    requirements. You specified: rmagick (>= 0) and rmagick (= 2.12.0.mswin32)`

Comment: That's unfortunate, what does Bundler complain about when you use the code from your original question?

Comment: Just look at my previous comment for the complain.

Comment: No I mean what does Bundler complain about when you have the exact Gemfile as in your original question. With using RUBY_PLATFORM.